# What are the translation of these two tanzaku in Date A Live II OVA?

Tags: japanese-language, date-a-live

In this scene in the **OVA** episode of **Date A Live Season 2**, the main setting is what appears to be a [*Tanabata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanabata) Festival.

In this first picture, Kotori was writing a wish on her *tanzaku* but as Tohka questioned her about it, she then entered *tsundere* mode. Before she managed to erase her original wish and replace it with a plain *"I hope Shidou becomes useful."*, the video shows her original wish for a few milliseconds, but there are no subtitles for it. (I'm sorry if the first character was already scratched out, but it was already very difficult to capture this image).

[image: Kotori's wish]

We also see Kurumi wrote her own wish in a *tanzaku*, but it isn't shown until much later in the episode. The second picture shows her wish as Shidou tied it to the topmost of a bamboo tree, again without subs.

[image: Kurumi's wish]

What did these two girls write in their wishes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially, Kotori wrote in her *tanzaku*

> 士道と結婚．．．

I don't know what lies beyond the cut off part, but it can be inferred that she wants to get married (結婚) with Shidou.

---

As for Kurumi's *tanzaku*, it reads

> 士道さんとまたいつか会えますように

which translates to

> I hope to meet Shidou-san again some day.

If you are wondering, the last 3 characters on the bottom left corner is her name [時崎]{ときさき}　狂{くるみ} (Tokisaki Kurumi).

Comment: What happened to the last three characters in Kurumi's *tanzaku*? Or are they irrelevant? I'm sorry, I don't know much about Japanese language.

Comment: @romcom_god: It is her name. Tokisaki Kurumi.